# Dockerでmysqlコンテナが起動後すぐにexited (1)になってしまう

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

#### 前提

docker-composeでlaravelの環境を立ち上げようとしているのですが、mysqlのコンテナが起動後すぐに`exited (1)` になってしまいます。

3日前くらいまでは起動していたのですが、急に正しい動作しなくなってしまいました。

#### 実現したいこと

- docker-composeでmysqlコンテナの起動がしたいです

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

- `docker-compose up- d` で起動をすると、mysqlコンテナのみすぐに`exited (1)`　になってしまいます

```
❯ docker-compose ps
NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
mysql_fargate       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  exited (1)
nginx_fargate       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   web                 running             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
php_fargate         "docker-php-entrypoi…"   app                 running             9000/tcp
```

- `docker-compose logs db`でログを見ると以下のようなエラーがでています。

```
mysql_fargate  | chown: changing ownership of './proc/94/task/96': Operation not permitted
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fd/4': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fd/5': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fd/6': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fd/7': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fd/8': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fd/9': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fdinfo/6': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fdinfo/7': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fdinfo/8': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/task/96/fdinfo/9': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fd/4': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fd/5': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fd/6': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fd/7': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fdinfo/6': No such file or directory
mysql_fargate  | chown: cannot access './proc/94/fdinfo/7': No such file or directory
```

権限周りの知識がなくご教授いただければ幸いです。

#### 該当のソースコード

- mysql/Dockerfile ↓

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mysql:8.0

COPY ./docker/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

- php/Dockerfile ↓

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

# COPY php.ini
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Composer install
COPY --from=composer:2.0 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# install Node.js
COPY --from=node:lts /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
COPY --from=node:lts /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    vim \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql bcmath

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

- nginx/Dockerfile ↓

```
FROM nginx:1.18-alpine

ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo

# nginx config file
COPY ./docker/nginx/*.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

- docker-compose.yml↓

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    container_name: php_fargate
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - "TZ=Asia/Tokyo"

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx_fargate
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT}:80
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
    container_name: mysql_fargate
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      TZ: 'Asia/Tokyo'
    volumes:
      - mysql-volume:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql-volume:
```

#### 試したこと

- docker system prune -aやvolumeの削除
- docker image, docker container の削除
- portの変更
- docker descktopでメモリの増加
- 他のコードでも試したのですが、うまく起動していないです

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

- Apple M1 Pro
- Laravel Framework 9.26.1
- node v16.17.0

Comment: 他のサイト [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/e87o7ngb02mh6v), [Qiita](https://qiita.com/tiger_taroo/questions/30fc86c0a2968f6edb0e) でも同じ内容の投稿をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 2):

自分も最近、MySQLのイメージを8.0.30から8.0.31に変更した際に同様の問題が発生しました。
どうやら原因はentrypointに`chown`の処理が追加された為でした。
https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/pull/797

これを見る限りログ系のファイルパスに相対パスを指定すると、意図しないディレクトリに対して`chown`を実行しようとしてしまうようです。
ですので、my.cnfで相対パスを指定しているようでしたら、絶対パスに置き換えてやることで回避が可能です。

Answer (score 0):

mysql/Dockerfile から以下の行をコメントアウトして、my.cnf の設定は別の方法で実現させる工夫をしてください。

```
COPY ./docker/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

ホストOSの設定に変更があったのか、my.cnfのCOPYを行う権限がなくなっていて、それを得るために（だめなんですけど）`chown` とかを実行しに行って結局ハネられているようです。